ping from script launched by cron
I found that it can not ping from the shell script launched by cron.
I wrote shell script like this:
#!/bin/bash

ping localhost
echo "Exit status: $?" >> /tmp/ping.log

And I configured crontab so that this script is executed at every minutes.
crontab -e
# I wrote `* * * * * /path/to/the/script`

In some minutes, I checked the file /tmp/ping.log. According to the log, the status code of ping was 127, indicating it failed.
When I execute ping in usual interactive shell by hand, It succeeds.
Why does it fail from cron ?

% type ping
ping is /sbin/ping

shows that the ping command is located in the /sbin directory, and adding
echo $PATH >> /tmp/ping.log

to the cron script shows that it is executed with a minimal PATH=/usr/bin:/bin. The status code is 127 because the executable is not found.
It is generally a good idea to use commands with absolute paths in cron scripts. The following worked as expected in my test. I have added a -c count argument because the ping command would not terminate otherwise.
#!/bin/bash

/sbin/ping -c 3 localhost >> /tmp/ping.log
echo "Exit status: $?" >> /tmp/ping.log

Alternatively one can extend the PATH in the shell script, so that it applies to the entire script:
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:$PATH
ping -c 3 localhost

One can even define the PATH for all cron scripts in the crontab itself:
# crontab
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin
* * * * * /path/to/the/script



When I execute ping in usual interactive shell by hand, It succeeds. Why does it fail from cron ?

The specific reason for the failure is that the environment in cron is a different environment than "... in usual interactive shell". If you want to learn how the environment is different in cron vs your interactive shell, try running printenv (or env) from each & observe the differences; i.e.:
% crontab -e
...  crontab opens in the editor you've chosen as default (an environment variable!!) 
...  add following line to your crontab: 

* * * * *  /usr/bin/printenv > $HOME/mycronenv.txt 2>&1

... save & exit the editor

Now, from your interactive shell, enter the following command:
% /usr/bin/printenv > $HOME/myshellenv.txt 2>&1 

Next, compare the environments listed in the two files:
cat $HOME/myshellenv.txt
...
cat $HOME/mycronenv.txt
...

See the difference? Note especially the difference in the PATH environment variable.
Next, find out where your ping command is located:
whereis ping
ping: /sbin/ping /usr/share/man/man8/ping.8

Ask yourself, "Is /sbin included in the PATH environment variable for cron?"
The answer is: "No"
What should I do about that?
Probably the easiest thing to do is change a line in your script:
FROM: 
ping localhost 

TO:
/sbin/ping -c 1 localhost

Please note the addition of -c 1 has nothing to do with environment, that is simply to keep you from clogging your system with a bunch of ping processes!!
One other thing you may need to do under macOS:

Open System Settings, then select Privacy and Security, and then Full Disk Access

Check to verify that cron is listed (and enabled) for "Full Disk Access"

IF IT IS LISTED, BUT NOT ENABLED: Click the toggle to enable it

IF IT IS NOT LISTED: Click the + at the bottom of the listing

Add cron (under /usr/sbin/cron to give cron "Full Disk Access")


And FWIW, see this recipe covering usage of cron & crontab
